# Rally User Story Parent feature

Tags: rally

I am trying to get those user stories that have parent of type feature. Here's my code:

```
QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
request.setFetch(new Fetch("Name,FormattedID, Parent, Feature"));
request.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Feature.FormattedID","=","F1119").and(new QueryFilter("Parent._type","=","PortfolioItem/Feature")));
QueryResponse response = this.rest.query(request);
if(response.wasSuccessful()){
....
}
```

The response returned is valid when I remove the `Parent Type` filter. I get those stories that have Feature `F119` . For some reason, when I explore the top level story in Rally, I can see that it has a parent Feature, but the Parent returned via query is `null`.

No stories are returned when I add `Parent Type` Query filter .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [WS API object model](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) a HierarchiclaRequirement object has `Parent` attribute that points to another HierarchiclaRequirement (a Parent story), a `Feature` attribute that references PI/Feature object that could be either its direct PI/Feature parent or the parent of it's parent user story, and a `PortfolioItem` attribute that points to its immediate PI/Feature parent

Given this scenario and hierarchiclarequirement queries below:
 US1 parent story and US2 child story, and the PI/Feature "parent" of US1 is F1:

```
(PortfolioItem.FormattedID = F1)
```

returns US1 that has a parent Feature. It does not return US2.

```
(Feature.FormattedID = F1)
```

returns both the epic and it's child, US1 and US2.